# How to add variable in this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is sample jQuery code

```
$('#HomeCity option:selected').text()
```

how do change HomeCity to optionElement[key] which from foreach function?

I did

```
$(" '#' + optionElement[key] option:selected ").text()
```

but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quotes properly to create correct selector.

*Use*

```
 $("#" + optionElement[key] + " option:selected ").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

make it

```
$( '#' + optionElement[key] + " option:selected ").text();
```

basically after `optionElement[key]` you need to start the quotes `"` again and before `'#'` no double quotes are required.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the code you mentioned wont be working because you have wraped it inside double quotes. So as per your code

```
$(" '#' + optionElement[key] option:selected ").text()
```

'#' + optionElement[key] option:selected is one string that jQuery is searching for and it doesnt exist in your page.

What you should be doing to make it dynamic is

```
$("#"+optionElement[key]+"option:selected").text()
```

This way your optionElement[key] is dynamic which will be changed as per the option selected.

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning